# Create and Load Custom Controls into FormView

Tags: visual-c++, dynamic, mfc, custom-controls

i have a Form View in MFC. I try to include a dynamic Field, like C# User Control, where i can include other Controls, based on the clicked Item in the Lists.

I already found a User Control in Toolbox.

My question is:

- Is it possible to create Form Views in Ressource View and add it to my Form View dynamically?
- Can I use the Custom User Control to Replace it with my created FormView?

  My FormView looks like this: [Imagelink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjKye.png) (Green Box should be filled with selected Control).
  It is embedded in a TabView Item.

Or if this didnt work, i would bind different FormViews (Create same FormView with different green controls) to that TabView without the Ressource View at Runtime, is that possible?

I'm new to MFC and created my Prototype in C# .NET, so this is very hard to understand :)

Comment: yes, it is possible. have a look: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763629/embedding-dialogs-in-main-dialog-and-switching-them-with-button-click-in-mfc)    [two](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4408/Creating-embedded-dialogs-in-MFC)

Comment: Thx for your comment, but i think this is not i meant. My main FormView is already in a Tabview, so that painted view is alredy embedded in that tab.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I'm now using different Groupboxes to arrange the Controls. I can show and hide them. Only the positioning should be a little bit hard.

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/32969/cstackablegroupbox-class-to-hide-group-of-controls