# How can I display a nested CDialog within another CDialog?

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I have two CDialog classes that I have created. Let's call them MainDialog and ExtraDialog. I want ExtraDialog to be able to be displayed both through doModal and as a nested dialog within MainDialog.

I can already bring it up separately through a Button and doModal. However, I've been stuck about how to place it within MainDialog.

```
CWnd* m_pWndStatic = new CWnd;
m_pWndStatic->Create(_T("Something"), _T("Title"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(x, y, xEnd, yEnd), this, idWnd);

CExtraDialog* dlg = new CExtraDialog;
dlg->Create(IDD_NEW_DIALOG, this); //Or second variable can be m_pWndStatic?
//dlg->SetWindowPos(m_pWndStatic, x, y, xEnd, yEnd, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
//dlg->Invalidate();
//dlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
//m_pWndStatic->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Above I shared some of the thigns I have tried. I was hoping to create a CWnd and put the dialog inside the CWnd but I feel like I am missing something and I couldn't really find anything helpful online.

Edit: I am basically trying to put multiple CWnds into one CDialog, and having the CWnd's run different functionalities from different classes. Kinda like putting lego blocks together.

Edit2: I found a question that is kinda similar? I hope to make it similar but I just don't want buttons and I want two of them get displayed at once.  [Embedding dialogs in main dialog and switching them with button click in MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763629/embedding-dialogs-in-main-dialog-and-switching-them-with-button-click-in-mfc)

Comment: Has your inner `CDialog` Style= Child? And Visible=True?

Comment: I haven't done anything other than what I posted in the question. Perhaps not? If I do dlg->ShowWindow(SW_WHOW), it pops it up in a separate window which isn't what I want. Sorry if I couldn't understand your question, I'm fairly new to MFC

Comment: Just put the code from the other question you found into your OnInitDialog function instead of a button handler. It can be repeated for each embedded dialog you need.

Comment: I'll try that and leave this question on until then! After (if) I (can) get it working, i'll post a solution for my own question if I can get it to work. Thank you

Comment: It displayed it as another Dialog inside the dialog but I want it to be fixed window that doesn't move around, kinda like a group box, a fixed simple section of display.

Comment: You need to set the proper styles on the child dialog window. You now have an answer that gives the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been stuck about how to place it within MainDialog.

At the minimum, remove `WS_POPUP`, `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_SYSMENU` styles. Add the [`WS_CHILD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) style.

It is highly recommended to add the [`WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) extended style to enable keyboard navigation into and out of the embedded dialog.

For example, in `OnInitDialog()` of the parent dialog you could add:

```
// Note: Create member variable CExtraDialog, so there is no need for dynamic allocation!
m_extraDlg.Create( IDD_NEW_DIALOG, this );

// Adjust styles. 1st parameter removes, 2nd adds.
m_extraDlg.ModifyStyle( WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME, WS_CHILD );

// Adjust extended styles. 1st parameter removes, 2nd adds.
m_extraDlg.ModifyStyleEx( WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT );

// As we have changed the frame, we let Windows recalculate the non-client area
// by passing the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag to SetWindowPos().
m_extraDlg.SetWindowPos( nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | 
     SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE );
```

> I was hoping to create a CWnd and put the dialog inside the CWnd

I recommend to always use a `CDialog`-derived class as the parent of an embedded dialog. This ensures best compatibility with the Windows dialog manager for features like standard keyboard navigation. You will work *with* the system, not against it.

More to read:

- [What is the DS_CONTROL style for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040730-00/?p=38293/)
- [Why doesn’t the TAB key work on controls I’ve marked as WS_TABSTOP?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100930-00/?p=12683/)
- [The dialog manager, part 2: Creating the frame window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050330-00/?p=36023)

Comment: I've combined your answer with the link I shared in my 2nd Edit and I have also used SetWindowPos for some extra properties: <SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_DRAWFRAME> from the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz Yeah, it's a good idea to make Windows recalculate the NC area after we have removed the border.